# "Quyer" When and why did the spelling change so drastically?

Tags: orthography, loanwords, french

[image: A picture snippet of text that reads (spelled as given): In the Quyer. Two paer of organs, and 6 lether stoles with iron to fit upon in the quyer, 4 great laten candlesticks before the base altar, and 1 other of iron. Two altar frontes, one of blew bawdkyn, the other of grene bawdkyn.]

The snippet above is  taken from *[The Gentleman's Magazine](https://books.google.it/books?id=umwdAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA483&dq=in%20the%20quyer%20Gentleman%20magazine&hl=en&sa=X&ei=As8aVJ-zF-XuyQOLvoH4Ag&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=quyer%20&f=false)* (London, England), Volume 53, dated, 1783.   It's only when you say ***Quyer*** out loud, do you realize what the word is. It is one of the quirkiest spelled words in the English language today, *[choir](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/choir)*, pronounced /ˈkwʌɪə/. Initially, ***quyer*** looks idiosyncratic and alien-looking, until you realize that the spelling is phonetic and what's more, it makes perfect sense. In addition, ***quyer*** looks *English* whereas the Modern English spelling of *choir* appears to be derived from the French *choeur*.

There are other instances of ***quyer*** in Google Books, published in [1715](https://books.google.it/books?id=jhRcAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA555&dq=quyer&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gdwbVKayMIqCzAOr6IGQCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quyer&f=false), [1726](https://books.google.it/books?id=LVJD1qg0FQsC&pg=RA1-PR18&dq=quyer&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XN4bVMa4EsahyAPzqYKgCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quyer&f=false), [1772](https://books.google.it/books?id=WgRJAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA81-IA1&dq=quyer&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ZtcbVP6qDIq6ygPK24LICw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quyer&f=false), and [1807](https://books.google.it/books?id=iKQMAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA404&dq=quyer&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QecbVO7JHKXpywO5ioGQAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=quyer&f=false)

When did the present day spelling ***choir*** definitely replace that of ***quyer***? Why wasn't the original (?), more English-looking, and more phonological *qu* kept?

EDIT
Many thanks to @Kris who kindly pointed out my error in the comments below.

> When did the present day spelling choir supersede that of quyer ?" It
>   did? No. nGram cited by Josh demonstrates that choir always was
>   dominant, while quyer lived a secondary existence until c.1825, when
>   it pretty much disappeared

Comment: Ngram suggests the coexistence of the two terms with choir  the more common of the two. 


   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quyer%2C%20choir&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquyer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchoir%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "When did the present day spelling *choir* supersede that of *quyer* ?" It did? No. nGram cited by Josh demonstrates that *choir* always was dominant, while *quyer* lived a secondary existence until c.1825, when it pretty much disappeared.

Comment: See the nGram (link corrected by moderator) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quyer%2Cchoir%2C%28quyer%2A100%29&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquyer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchoir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28quyer%20%2A%20100%29%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Kris: how reliable is ngram for old sources, and how reliable are statistics with small sample sizes (there seem to be few occurrences even of _choir_)? I'm not sure ngram is the tool to use when looking into a spelling used from around 1400 (according to etymonline).

Comment: @oerkelens That's true. However, a deeper research into it would have got an "answer," not a "comment" to post here (with maybe a PhD to boot?)

Comment: Don't forget that books and even writing were limited to a small proportion of the population and due to invasions, etc. writing in particular over speech had more influence by the French.

Comment: note that you might be better to put a link word in brackets followed by the link in parentheses. [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quyer%2Cchoir%2C(quyer*100)&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cquyer%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bquyer%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BQuyer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cchoir%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bchoir%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BChoir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28quyer%20%2A%20100%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's a multiplier in case the term isn't in the same scale as the other term(s). You can use the multiplier to force the graphs to be on the same percentage lines.

Comment: @SrJoven I see, I didn't know you could do that with Ngrams.

Comment: With respect to date, note that all of your sources except the last are transcripts of MSS dating to the reign of Henry VIII - first half of the 16th century, more than a century before spelling was regularized toward the end of the 17th century.

Comment: Ok sorry, delete your comments.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***Quyer*** and ***choir*** possibly have different meanings.

From the context you gave, it looks like ***quyer*** is the equivalent of the modern-day word ***quire***. A ***quire*** is not a group of singers, but rather it's the part of a church where those singers sit.

***Choir*** is clearly a strongly related word, describing the group of singers. To muddy the water a bit, the spelling ***choir*** is also a commonly used alternative spelling for ***quire***.

So it looks to me like rather than the spelling ***quyer*** dying out and being replaced by ***choir***, the history of the words is more like this:

- Before English spelling was codified, there were a variety of spellings for this word, and it could be used to refer both to the singers, and the place where they sit.
- Once spelling started to standardize, people used ***quyer*** (and variations on it) for the place, and ***choir*** (and variations on it) for the singers.
- ***Quyer*** looks kind of weird, and eventually evolved into ***quire***, which looks like a more normal English spelling.
- Nowadays, very few people who are not experts at church architecture will frequently encounter the word ***quire***, so end up using ***choir*** instead, which would account for the [declining usage of ***quire***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=choir%2Cquire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchoir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cquire%3B%2Cc0).

(I personally am only familiar with the term ***quire*** from having to [sit in one](http://www.terragalleria.com/europe/united-kingdom/canterbury/picture.uken36082.html) at a wedding I recently attended.)

Comment: Indeed, the insert context image/text certainly backs this up, as it indicates equipment existing within the place.

Comment: The carol *The Holly and the Ivy* had the refrain "The playing of the merry organ, sweet singing in the quire" though apparently "choir" started to be the spelling of the final word from the late 19th century.

Comment: Also note that the modern definitions of `quire` relate generally to pieces of paper or parchment: 1) four sheets of paper or parchment folded to form eight leaves, as in medieval manuscripts. 2) any collection of leaves one within another in a manuscript or book. 3) 25 (formerly 24) sheets of paper; one twentieth of a ream. In my experience the third definition is the one I've seen most commonly.

Answer (score 6):

[etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=choir&searchmode=none) says this:

> c.1300, queor "part of the church where the choir sings," from Old French cuer, quer "choir of a church (architectural); chorus of singers" (13c., Modern French choeur), from Latin chorus "choir" (see chorus). Meaning "band of singers" is c.1400, quyre. Re-spelled mid-17c. on Latin model.

Contrary to my initial instinct, the *qu* seems to actually have been an Old French spelling change (I would usually assume *qu* to be more Latin than French).

The 17th century respelling seems to have been aimed at reflecting the actual origin of the word from Latin (this etymological spelling was at the basis of many respelling efforts) but it did end up making the word look more like modern French instead. A case of historic irony?

I guess the old spelling of *quyer* survived for a while out of habit, or possibly because people did not actually associate *choir* with the same, but differently spelled *choir* (which may well have looked like a newly-borrowed French word).

Comment: The Prayer book has "In quires and places where they sing".

Comment: @TimLymington: According to wiki, that was published in 1662, indeed around mid 17c. that etymonline mentions. As such the spelling _i_ for the vowel _y_ is not uncommon, but it is interesting to see that (_i_ for _y_) reflected in the “new” spelling as well.

Comment: But, "When did the present day spelling *choir* supersede that of *quyer* ?"

Comment: @Kris: That is a very good, and admittedly still unanswered question if it means "when did the _use_ of one supersede the _use_ of the other_". Google ngrams does not have enough occurrences of either word to really be able to tell, apart from the fact that it becomes less trustworthy in general the further we go back from say, 1800. Etymonline clearly states the spelling (maybe not the usage) was reformed in the 17th century so that is when the choir spelling superseded the quyer spelling (albeit in a prescriptivist sense - but that was OK back then).

Comment: Please see the nGram I cited at OP. HTH.